# 2D Poisson equation with Piecewise RHS - symbolic solution?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following 2D Poisson equation symbolically:
$$
-\nabla^2 u(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
      1-\text{sech}\left(\frac{w}{2 d}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{x}{d}\right) 
& -w/2 \leq x\leq w/2 \quad \text{and} \; -t/2 \leq y\leq t/2\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
where $d$ is a parameter and $w,t$ describe the width and thickness of the rectangle over which the source is nonzero.

```
inhomogeneousFunction[x_, y_] = 
 Piecewise[{{(1 - Sech[w/(2 d)] Cosh[x/d]), -w/2 <= x <= w/2 && -t/2 <= y <= t/2}}]
```

So far, I've tried the following to little success:

1. `DSolve` using `Piecewise` restriction

```
DSolve[-Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]==inhomogeneousFunction[x,y],u[x,y],{x,y}]
```

(returns unevaluated)

2. `DSolve` without `Piecewise` restriction

```
DSolve[-Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]==inhomogeneousFunction[x,y][[1,1,1]],u[x,y],{x,y}]

{{u[x, y] -> 
   1/2 Sech[w/(
     2 d)] (-x^2 Cosh[w/(2 d)] + 2 d^2 Cosh[x/d] + 
      2 Cosh[w/(2 d)] C[1][x - I y] + 2 Cosh[w/(2 d)] C[2][x + I y])}}
```

(returns general solution, but I'm not sure how to use the piecewise restriction to solve for the integration constants?)

3. `GreenFunction`

```
greenFunction[m_,n_]=GreenFunction[-Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}],u[x,y],{x,y}∈ FullRegion[2],{m,n}]
Integrate[
 FullSimplify[greenFunction[m, n] inhomogeneousFunction[m,n]], {m,-∞,∞},{n, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> (w | t | x | y) ∈ Reals]
```

(returns unevaluated)

4. Solve in the Fourier domain using
   $$
   \tilde{u} = \tilde{f}/k^2
   $$
   where $f$ is the `Piecewise` function defined above, $k^2=k_x^2+k_y^2$, and we're using tildes to define Fourier-transformed quantities.

```
inhomogeneousFunctionFT[kx_, ky_] = 
 FullSimplify[
  FourierTransform[inhomogeneousFunction[x, y], {x, y}, {kx, ky}, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, 
   Assumptions -> Thread[{d, w, t} > 0]], 
  Assumptions -> Thread[{d, w, t} > 0]]

With[{k2 = {kx, ky} . {kx, ky}},
 InverseFourierTransform[
  inhomogeneousFunctionFT[kx, ky]/k2, {kx, ky}, {x, y}, 
  Assumptions -> Thread[{d, w, t} > 0], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]
```

FT is computed analytically as follows
$$
\tilde{f} = \frac{4 \sin \left(\frac{\text{ky} t}{2}\right) \left(\sin \left(\frac{\text{kx} w}{2}\right)-d \text{kx} \tanh \left(\frac{w}{2 d}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\text{kx} w}{2}\right)\right)}{\text{kx} \text{ky} \left(d^2 \text{kx}^2+1\right)}
$$
but `InverseFourierTransform` struggles, perhaps due to the singularity at $k=0$?

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would consider using a Fourier series (limited to your rectangle, or its periodic extension).

Comment: @mikado It's not the right way to go, I'm afraid. According to OP's statement, he's solving the problem on full 2D region.

Comment: I'd argue that you've already obtained the symbolic solution in 3rd and 4th trial. They're symbolic solutions involving integral. Actually if you calculate the integral at a specific point in 3rd approach, `Integrate` manages to give an answer: `Integrate[greenFunction[m, n] inhomogeneousFunction[m, n] /. {w -> 1, t -> 2, d -> 3, x -> 4, y -> 5}, {m, -∞, ∞}, {n, -∞, ∞}] // AbsoluteTiming`, but it involves `SinhIntegral` and `CoshIntegral`, so integral (or series, perhaps) may not be avoidable for the symbolic solution.

Comment: @xzczd once you have a solution for the region, you can add the solution for the Laplace equation `a x + b y + c` to get the solution for the whole plane.

Comment: @mikado I'm sorry but I fail to understand what method you're refering to, can you elaborate a bit?